# How two different users can be logged in at the same time in the same browser

Tags: asp.net, authentication, owin

I'm using ASP.NET Web forms including OWIN authentication.
for now it's using *ApplicationCookie* as AuthenticationType.
what i want is while a user is logged in, try to **login as** another user (with another role) without losing first user authentication data similar to Google Account mechanism.

I thought to authenticate the second user using token placed in query string but i don't know how to handle authentication codes so it changes the authenticated User based on the query string token.

Comment: I have never seen Google's apps work the way you mention.  If you log in with another tab in the same instance of the browser, then the first instance changes to new instance.  And cookieless authentication is typically a bad idea.  see http://brockallen.com/2012/04/08/cookieless-session-considered-dangerous/

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch When you are logged in Google Account (ex: gmail), you can use Add Account to login with another account, and you can then switch between them using the Account Menu! and also you can manage two accounts in two tabs. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't want to you to solve my problem. please note that i shared an abstract already. I want suggestions. to clarify my problem, i don't know how to change OWIN context so based on the query string token, OWIN ignores the main/old cookie information, and uses the new auth info.

Comment: @Mahyar - That's a very different thing.  Google is still using a single identity that you are logged in with.  That identity is just given access to the other email accounts data.  All this is doing is letting multiple email accounts be managed by the same login account (note that login and email accounts are different things).  That is just a matter of your data model is defined to allow many to many associations between your email accounts and user accounts.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809401/key-cloak-two-users-with-differents-roles-logged-in-in-the-same-time

Comment: @EstevanDiedrich no, that's something else. what i meant is that you are admin/supervisor and you are logged in, and you have changed/created some property for one of your basic users, and you want to log in as that user in a different tab in the same browser without loosing your admin session, to check the user profile. now i think it may be able to do this with a session created key in querystring. when user logged off, you delete the session key